# Spring Boot executable RUN_ARGS in conf file

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line-arguments, executable-jar

When I use init.d service with `conf` file and put inside custom:

`RUN_ARGS=--spring.config.location=/usr/share/application/config/app.properties`

similar to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4281

Service starts as it is expected

However, if I have default name and location `application.properties` but need to pass for instance `--logging.config` :

`RUN_ARGS=--logging.config=/usr/share/application/config/logback-spring.xml`

service does not start up and I do not see any messages, even after adding `DEBUG=true` to `conf` file

**Edit** : similar issue with `JAVA_OPTS` :

`JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"`

works fine, but for instance

`JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1024m"`

service start up failed